# Restore history for moved files in TFS

Tags: version-control, tfs, revision-history, tfs-2015

A while ago, I moved a large number of files into an new project to better organize my program. Now I have discovered that all history have disappeared since TFS (of course) solve it by removing the files from the old location and create new files in the new location.

My question is whether it is at all possible to restore the history for the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can only be accomplished by using a migration tool like OpsHub or the [TFS Migration Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eb77e739-c98c-4e36-9ead-fa115b27fefe).

You will have to destroy the files in their current location, do the migration and then re-do the changes made since the migration. There is no way to check in the history "behind" already checked in files.

How badly do you need the history? And Could you live with the history being in the old project?